# Invalid template path from github but not when doing it directly in cli Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, stack, command-line-interface, aws-cloudformation

I try to perform an aws cloudformation deploy from github, but it indicates that the template is malformed. When performing the same operation from the CLi console or directly in AWS Cloudformation if the stack is generated, what could be the problem?

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Template para la creacion de Lambdas en AWS CloudFormation.
Parameters:
  Ambiente:
    Type: String
    Description: Ambiente (Ej desarrollo, preproduccion o produccion).
    AllowedPattern: ^.*[^0-9]$
    ConstraintDescription: Must end with non-numeric character.
  LambdaName:  
    Type: String
    Description: Nombre del lambda que se desea crear.
    AllowedPattern: ^.*[^0-9]$
    ConstraintDescription: Must end with non-numeric character.
  Runtime:  
    Type: String
    Description: Version de Nodejs (Ej nodejs14.x, nodejs16.x , nodejs18.x)
    AllowedPattern: ^.*[^0-9]$
    ConstraintDescription: Must end with non-numeric character.
   
Outputs:
  LambdaRoleARN:
    Description: Role for Lambda execution.
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - LambdaRole
        - Arn
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-ExRole"
  LambdaFunctionName:
    Value:
      Ref: LambdaFunction
  LambdaFunctionARN:
    Description: Lambda function ARN.
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - LambdaFunction
        - Arn
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: arn:aws:lambda:sa-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:function:${LambdaName}
Resources:
  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName:
        Fn::Sub: lambda-role-${LambdaName}
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
              - lambda.amazonaws.com
        Version: 2012-10-17
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaExecute
      Path: /
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        Fn::Sub: lambda-${LambdaName}
      Description: LambdaFunction of nodejs14.x.
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime:
        Fn::Sub: ${Runtime}
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          exports.handler = async (event) => {
            // TODO implement
            const response = {
              statusCode: 200,
              body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
            };
            return response;
          };
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 60
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - LambdaRole
          - Arn
```

aws cloudformation deploy --template-file plantilla_test.yaml --stack-name plantillalambdagithub --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you defined few parameters but you don't give default values. Therefore, you either give them values with the command you attempted to execute or define them in a JSON file.

### Execute with command

```bash
aws cloudformation deploy \
    --template-file plantilla_test.yaml \
    --stack-name plantillalambdagithub \
    --parameter-overrides Runtime=nodejs18.x LambdaName=rainmaker Ambiente=produccion \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

You could use `aws cloudformation deploy help` to look up the detail of each arguments for the deployment command.

### Execute with command and JSON file

#### Create the JSON file for parameters

```bash
cat <<EOL > parameters.json
{
    "Parameters":
    {
        "Runtime": "nodejs18.x",
        "LambdaName": "rainmaker",
        "Ambiente": "produccion"
    }
}
EOL
```

#### Execute the deployment command

```bash
aws cloudformation deploy \
    --template-file plantilla_test.yaml \
    --stack-name plantillalambdagithub \
    --parameter-overrides file://parameters.json \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

2 files, i.e. the JSON file and CFN template are all under the same directory.

Comment: thx for comment. I changed the template and set the default values, still it shows the same error

Comment: Use the template you presented on this page and the way I mentioned to give the parameters value, you shall be able to deploy the resources. If you want to know why the template where the parameters have default value cannot work, more information will be helpful.